# Nested global variables / Defining a variable in a nested function

Tags: python-3.x, nested, global-variables, global

I am writing a program and stumbled across a problem. I have a 'counter' counting how many wins for the computer and player. The problem is, my function is nested in another. How would I accomplish this without an `UnboundLocalError`? Where do I put the `global` statement or how would I accomplish it?

```
def nestedfunction():
    print("I am nested")
    score += 1
    print(score)
    again = input("would you like to play again? > ")
    if again == "yes":
         function()
else:
    exit()
def function():
    print("I am not nested")
    nestedfunction()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    score = 0
    function()
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**:

```
I am not nested.
I am nested.
1
would you like to play again? > yes
I am not nested.
I am nested.
2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a variable that is not local then put a global before it to access the global variable

```
    def nestedfunction():
        print("I am nested")
        global score 
        score += 1
        print(score)
        again = raw_input("would you like to play again?>")
        if str(again) == "yes":
            function()
        else:
            exit()

    def function():
        print("I am not nested")
        nestedfunction() 
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        score = 0
        function()
```

It would be better if you sent the score as parameter rather than using global